Fourier Analysis, Stein and Shakarchi, Chapter 6 Exercise 10
Problem
Let $u(x, t)$ be a solution of the wave equation, and let $E(t)$ denote the energy of this wave
$$E(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x, t)\right|^2dx + \sum_{j = 1}^d \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}(x, t)\right|^2 dx.$$
We have seen that $E(t)$ is constant using Plancherel's formula. Give an alternate proof of this fact by differentiating the integral with respect to $t$ and showing that
$$\frac{dE}{dt} = 0$$
Attempt
I have a solution that relies on the validity of interchanging the derivative and the integral, but I am having trouble justifying why it's okay to do so. In particular, I wish to show that
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial E(t)}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial }{\partial t} \left[ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x, t)\right)^2dx + \sum_{j = 1}^d \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}(x, t)\right)^2 dx \right] \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x, t)\right)^2dx + \sum_{j = 1}^d \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}(x, t)\right)^2 dx 
\end{align*}
$$
Once I can show this, the rest of the proof follows quite straightforwardly, but I don't know how to justify this. I'm tempted to invoke the Leibniz integral rule but that only applies to proper integrals, where we have repeated improper integrals here.

Suppose $f(t,x)$ is continuously differentiable in $t$. If for every $t$ in some neighborhood of $t_0$, one has $|f(t,x)|\leq g(x)$ with $\int g<\infty$, then $\partial_t\int f(t,x),dx = \int \partial_t f(t,x),dx$.
